# How do two nodes discover each other by a third node in a private blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, synchronization, bootnodes

I'm using geth in three different containers.

*Note: start a container means start `geth` and start mining.*

Each container has its ports exposed.

- A: `-p 30303:30303 -p 8545:8545`;
- B: `-p 30304:30303 -p 8546:8545`;
- C: `-p 30305:30303 -p 8547:8545`.

They are started in the following way:

- Start the containers A, B and C;
- Stop containers B and C;
- Get the first node address and start containers B and C using it:
  `--bootnodes "enode://<first_node_address>@<host_ip>:30303"`.

After that, I can see the block mining **is synchronized** in each container. So far so good.

Then **stop the container A**. The problem is here, containers B and C are mining but **not** synchronized. There is no communication between them.

How do I make the nodes B and C know each other using A so they can continue to sync even if the node A fall.

---

I tried to use the bootnode service but they never synchronized.

I generated the bootnode key and started the bootnode service in A. Then I started A, B and C with the bootnode address of A using `--bootnodes "enode://<bootnode_address>@<host_ip>:30303"`.